# How to find $avg in mongodb query with python pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, average

I am having hard time finding $avg in a mongodb query:
The code i have used look like this:

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbtime.aggregate({ "$avg": "$id13"})
```

Output:`pipeline must be a list`

I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All aggregate queries must be passed as lists in pymongo, and any aggregation must be part of a group or projection. Try this:

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbtime.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': 0,
        'avg_id13': {'$avg': '$id13'}
    }}])
```

Comment: It works but when i print the results it shows me 723 avg ids but i only wanted only one for the whole file.Why is happening?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I Wanted the average id13 from 1million rows.When i print my cursor with for x in cursor:  pprint(x)  it shows me 723 unique averages in total instead of one for all.